# Package 'php-pear' has no installation candidate

Tags: ubuntu, php, apt, pear

I am trying to install `apt install php-pear` and I get this error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package php-pear is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php-pear' has no installation candidate
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have ran out of ideas.

I already tried `apt-get update` and many other things but I can't seem to get it working. This is an `Ubuntu 20.04.4` server running at DigitalOcean using `PHP 8.0.29` (cli)

Comment: Current Ubuntu 20.04 release is 20.04.6 and there is no `php8.0` package there. So, for a start, you can upgrade your system.